# Get only date without time from REST query on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, sharepoint

I have a date column on a Custom List. The format of that column can be set on Edit Column Page and it displays only date as expected on my Custom List page. But then I want to create a REST query by using ajax and display it on console log for debugging. The date is display as follow:

```
    Date_x0020_Borrow:"2016-08-08T17:00:00Z"
```

Are there any ways to make it return only mm/dd/yyyy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that api but you can easly parse date with plain JavaScript.

```
var date_tz = "2016-08-08T17:00:00Z";
f_z =  function(v) { if(parseInt(v) < 10) return "0"+v; return $v;}; // filling with 0 if needed

var d = new Date(date_tz);
d = f_z(d.getDate()) + '/' + f_z((d.getMonth()+1)) + '/' + d.getFullYear();

alert(d); // "08/08/2016"
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will work using java script:

```
var eventDate = new Date('your SharePoint column value');
var dd =  eventDate.getDate(); 
var mm = eventDate.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = eventDate.getFullYear();

if(dd < 10){
        dd = '0' + dd;
            } 
if(mm < 10){
         mm = '0' + mm;
            } 
formattedEventDate = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
```

OR using angular:

Date_x0020_Borrow | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'